# math opperation between a SpatRaster and a vectors using terra package

Tags: overlay, algebra, terra

I have a simple question about `app()` family function

I want to divide a vector (of n values) by a raster and to get n resulting rasters

```
s <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))[[1]] 

lapp(s, aa = c(1, 10, 100, 1000), function(x, aa){0.46 * aa/(x + 1)})
```

The same would like to know to be done with a SpatRasterDataset. Is that possible?

Here is an example:

```
fun = function(i, j) { 
    v <- c(1, 10, 100, 1000)
    f <- i + j
    v / f
}
srd <- sds(list(i = s, j = s/10))
r <- lapp(srd, fun = fun, recursive = TRUE )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do (using a slightly modified example to make it easier to see what happens):

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10)
s <- init(s, 1:10)
v <- c(1, 10, 100, 1000)    
a <- app(s, function(x, aa){ sapply(aa, function(i) 2 * i/x) }, aa=v)
a
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#names       : lyr.1, lyr.2, lyr.3 
#min values  :   0.2,   2.0,  20.0 
#max values  :     2,    20,   200
```

With `terra` version 1.3-17 (currently the development version), you can now also do:

```
b <- 2 * v/s
```

to get the same results. The layers of a SpatRaster are recycled when doing arithmetic with a vector that is longer than the number of layers.

With a SpatRasterDataSet you can do something like the below. It is important to test `fun` outside of `lapp` to see if the number of values returned, and their order, make sense.

```
fun = function(i, j) { 
    v <- c(1, 10, 100, 1000)
    f <- i + j
    f <- rep(f, each=length(v))
    matrix(v / f, ncol=length(v), byrow=TRUE)
}
srd <- sds(list(i = s, j = s/10))
r <- lapp(srd, fun = fun)
```

Comment: Is this an example or should I ask another question?;


```
fun = function(i, j) {
  v <- c(1, 10, 100, 1000);
  o = j/(1 + j);
  f = i * o;
  r1 = 0.5 * v/(f + 1);
  return(r1);
};

srd <- sds(i = s, j = s/10);
funResult <- lapp(srd, fun = fun, recursive = TRUE )
```

Comment: This is not what comments are for. I have edited your question for you